# VBA Excluding items from filter when they're not always there

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot, pivot-table

Im trying to automatically exclude certain items from a Pivot table, there are some customers that i dont want to ever include, ive got the following VBA which seems to exclude them, but if they are not on the data the next time i run it, it cant find them to exclude and then stops working.
is there a way to get it to ignore the customer if it cant find them and move on to the next one?

```
Sub Filtering()


    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("CUSTOMER NAME"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("CUSTOMER NAME")
        .PivotItems("Customer1").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Customer2").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Customer3").Visible = False

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have posted an answer with fresh edits. you may have to refresh the page to see the edits

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to get it to ignore the customer if it cant find them and move on to the next one?

Two ways I can quickly think of. Take your pick :)

**WAY 1**

Check if the pivot item exists and then try to work with it. Also it is best if you use Objects. Easy to manage your code.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Dim pField As PivotField

Sub Filtering()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim pTbl As PivotTable
    Set pTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    
    Set pField = pTbl.PivotFields("CUSTOMER NAME")
    
    pField.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
    With pField
        If DoesPivotItemExist("Customer1") Then .PivotItems("Customer1").Visible = False
        If DoesPivotItemExist("Customer4") Then .PivotItems("Customer4").Visible = False
        If DoesPivotItemExist("Customer3") Then .PivotItems("Customer3").Visible = False
    End With
End Sub

'~~> Function to check if the pivot item exists
Private Function DoesPivotItemExist(pvtItem As String) As Boolean
    Dim pitm As PivotItem
    
    For Each pitm In pField.PivotItems
        If pitm.Name = pvtItem Then
            DoesPivotItemExist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next pitm
End Function
```

**WAY 2**

Use `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` to hide the item without checking if they exist or not

For example

```
Option Explicit

Dim pField As PivotField

Sub Filtering()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim pTbl As PivotTable
    Set pTbl = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable2")
    
    Set pField = pTbl.PivotFields("CUSTOMER NAME")
    
    pField.CurrentPage = "(All)"
    
    With pField
       HidePivotItem "Customer1"
       HidePivotItem "Customer2"
       HidePivotItem "Customer4"
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub HidePivotItem(pvtItem As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    pField.PivotItems(pvtItem).Visible = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```